# PIe Chart not displayed

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-charts

here is my tab's code containing the pie chart

```
{
                                xtype: 'container',
                                title: 'Chart',
                                iconCls: 'chart',
                                itemId: 'chart_Tab',
                                layout: {
                                    type: 'fit'
                                },
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'polar',
                                        autoDestroy: false,
                                        colors: [
                                            '#115fa6',
                                            '#94ae0a',
                                            '#a61120',
                                            '#ff8809',
                                            '#ffd13e',
                                            '#a61187',
                                            '#24ad9a',
                                            '#7c7474',
                                            '#a66111'
                                        ],
                                        store: 'elementstore',
                                        series: [
                                            {
                                                type: 'pie',
                                                xField: 'numValue'
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        interactions: [
                                            {
                                                type: 'rotate'
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
```

Problem is, it does show anything, but does not crash either...
I checked my store is full of model to display.

Here is the output of this chart...  All there is is the ''gpl sencha generated label'' no chart at all... so im guessing something is wrong but I cant put my finger on it, + there is absolutly NO working exemple of that from the sencha team...

Still not working would someone has anny idea on why?

[image: output]

Comment: what about firebug errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Charts files are not included with the free version of Sencha Touch, nor in the trial version.
2. If you run it in a local sever (app.html) and not index.html, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
store: 'elementstore',
```

To

```
`store: elementstore,`,
```

Comment: I can't, architect wrote that line for me. I can't modifiy it and it's supposed to be writte that way I guess if the software does it like that :S